# finding Coordinates of Cap of an arrow

Tags: geometry

I have to draw an arrow. I have a head point and a tail point now i need to draw a triangular arrow cap. A triangle whose length is of size 5.How can i find coordinates of the end points of triangle. One thing is we have angle of 45.so if we can rotate the vector by 45 to obtain it.

Comment: Ok i have removed that tag..Any clue for the algorithm using which i can get the points

Answer (score 0):

$h$: position vector of head point
$t$: position vector of tail point
$l$: length of cap
$w$: width of cap
$\alpha$: angle of cap tip

We want to find $c_1$ and $c_2$, the two unknown points of the cap triangle. The third is $h$.

[image]

**If $w$ is given:**

Direction vector (normalized) of head to tail: $d = \frac{t-h}{|t-h|}$.

The end of the cap on the line between head and tail: $c=h+d \cdot l$.

The two directions perpendicular to $d$:
$d_1 = (-d_y, d_x)$
$d_2 = (d_y, -d_x)$

$c_1 = c + \frac{1}{2} \cdot w \cdot d_1$
$c_2 = c + \frac{1}{2} \cdot w \cdot d_2$

**Finding $w$**:

The cap triangle is symmetric and consists of two mirrored right-angled triangles. In a right-angled triangle, $\tan(\phi) = \frac{opposite}{adjacent}$.

$$\tan(90°-\frac{1}{2}\alpha) = \frac{l}{\frac{1}{2}w} \\
w = \frac{2l}{\tan(90°-\frac{1}{2}\alpha)} \approx 4.142 $$